# How to avoid plotting certain values of a series with matplotplib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to plot a dataframe column with matplotlib, but I don't want to see the trend when the series value is 0 or higher. I also would like to see properly the x axis, without the overlapping. I don't want to remove these values from the series, because of the date it is important to be able to see them as blank space.

Right now, I have the following simple code:

```
plt.plot(data, linestyle='dashed')
plt.title('Points')
plt.ylabel('Number')
plt.xlabel('Time (days)')
plt.show(block = True)
```

[image]

Where **data** is the following df:

```
Tagname
01/06/2008 00:00   -45.757616
02/06/2008 00:00   -45.990457
03/06/2008 00:00   -45.393121
04/06/2008 00:00   -44.913295
05/06/2008 00:00   -44.705479
                      ...    
19/03/2012 00:00   -53.729701
20/03/2012 00:00   -53.453338
21/03/2012 00:00   -52.822274
22/03/2012 00:00   -52.814657
23/03/2012 00:00   -52.900613
Name: points_subs, Length: 3314, dtype: float64
```

How can I do both things???

Comment: `data[data>0].plot()`?

Comment: make sure the times are actually datetimes as well, `pd.to_datetime`

Answer (score 0):

There's a feature that automatically optimizes the x-axis for you. The `matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator` [matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html?highlight=dates#module-matplotlib.dates)is used. Does your quality match your intentions?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

data = (np.random.randint(0, 60, (3314,)) + np.random.rand(3314)) * -1
date = pd.date_range('2008-06-01', '2017-06-27', freq='1D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':data}, index=pd.to_datetime(date))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,9),dpi=144)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

plt.plot(df.index, df['data'], linestyle='dashed')

plt.title('Points')
plt.ylabel('Number')
plt.xlabel('Time (days)')

locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.show(block = True)
```

[image]